# Yodlee REST API - user registration with register3

Tags: rest, yodlee

I am trying to follow Yodlee's **Aggregation REST Quick Start Guide**.

Using **Postman**, I can successfully call `https://rest.developer.yodlee.com/services/srest/restserver/v1.0/authenticate/coblogin` and obtain the `sessionToken`. However, whenever I try to register a new user using **rest3** (`https://rest.developer.yodlee.com/services/srest/restserver/v1.0/jsonsdk/UserRegistration/register3`) I am getting the following error:

```
{
  "errorOccurred": "true",
  "exceptionType": "Exception Occurred",
  "referenceCode": "_1eed175d-4d05-4644-9a84-913976e9799b"
}
```

which is not very informative.

I think this might be related to the ***sandbox environment*** and the ***evaluation mode***, but I have not been able to find any documentation that can help me.

Is there a way I can register users using **register3** or do I have to somehow upgrade my Yodlee account so I can register new users instead of using the mocked ones provided by them?

**EDIT**

If instead of using API **v1.0** I call the **v2.0** version, the error message changes to:

```
{
  "errorOccurred": "true",
  "exceptionType": "com.yodlee.core.InsufficientPrivilegeException",
  "referenceCode": "_8c56247e-8f40-4fd4-89d9-e8bdc10fba66",
  "message": "Accessibility denied."
}
```

is this because I am using the sandbox environment and I don't have enough permissions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using v1.0 only for all the APIs. But on this sandbox environment this particular API is restricted. You need to work with Yodlee Sales to get you your dedicated environment, where you won't be having any such restriction.

On the side note, do share the the request you are sending for a particular API call in future, as this will help in debugging the issue.